# OpenGL multiple frame buffer rendering

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I'm creating a simple WebGL 3D engine and now I'm trying to add some post processing effects.
I do this way: I draw the scene using a Frame Buffer and render to a texture, than I pass the texture to my simple post-processing shader, that renders to the actual physical screen (I follow the openGL post-processing tutorial: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Post-Processing).

creation of the frame buffer:

```
// texture
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
frameBufferTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);  
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);   
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);  

// depth buffer
frameBufferDepth = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, frameBufferDepth);
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);

// framebuffer to link everything together
frameBufferObject = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObject);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture, 0);
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, frameBufferDepth);

// check status
var success = (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
if (success)    
    console.log('post processing frame object created');                
else
    throw "could not create post processing frame: " + gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);

// vertices
var fbo_vertices = [
    -1.0, -1.0,
     1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0
];
frameBufferVertices = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, frameBufferVertices);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(fbo_vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

then, when I draw the scene, I call:

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObject);
```

to target the frame buffer

and I finally render the texture to the screen with the basic shader (does nothing except take the points of the texture):

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null); 

gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);     
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clearDepth(1.0); 
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);      
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);
gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.fbo_texture, 0);     

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, frameBufferVertices);        
gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.fbo_vertex, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);                

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

At this point all works perfectly, now my idea was to use multiple shaders (every shader with a different program), that share the same Frame Buffer, so every shader takes in input the texture and write to it.

I tried to use multiple shaders and calls in a for cycle (for every shader):

```
gl.useProgram(postProcessingProgram);   

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObject); 

gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);     
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clearDepth(1.0); 
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);        

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, frameBufferTexture);
gl.uniform1i(postProcessingProgram.basic_texture, 0);                   

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, frameBufferVertices);        
gl.vertexAttribPointer(postProcessingProgram.fbo_vertex, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);                

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

except for the last basic shader that render to the physical screen

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

the screen is totally black, but I receive no error or warning. It doesn't work even if I use the same basic shader twice.

My question is: is it correct to use the same frame buffer for multiple shaders? If I use multiple frame buffer, how can I share the same texture to do the consecutive steps?

Comment: Right off the bat, it looks like you are trying to sample from the same texture you are drawing into. This will give you undefined results as it creates what newer versions of the OpenGL specification refer to as a feedback loop. Ping-ponging between two or more textures (e.g. swap the texture drawn into and sampled from for each pass) is the usual approach pre-GL4. Have a look [here](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis565/fbo.htm#feedback) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Try debugging with webGL inspector.